# Simple Tool or script to sort in folders and by date RAW images in linux?

Tags: raw, metadata, file-management, linux, exiftool

I'm taking a lot of RAW photos lately and I need a simple but convenient way to organize them.
I saw a lot of tools to sort JPG images using EXIF informations, but **none of them actually works with RAW files**... Don't know why since a JPG is embedded by design in each RAW.

Anyway, does someone knows about a way to do this? A simple command line based script is fine, I just need something that reads the images in a folders and organize them in sub-folders based on the time the photo was taken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) reads many raw formats.

You can use a command similar to this one to rename your photo files :

```
exiftool '-filename<CreateDate' -d %y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%le -r -ext cr2  /path/to/pictures
```

Change `cr2` to whatever your raw extension is, and `/path/to/pictures` to the desired folder.  Once renamed, you can sort them by name.  There are more examples [here](http://ninedegreesbelow.com/photography/exiftool-commands.html).

Note that reading raw files will probably always be a moving target since the formats are usually proprietary and camera manufacturers can change them as they please, but ExifToool seems to support so many of them that you're probably covered.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
In the section "3. Move or Copy image files into folders by year and month " of the page you linked I found a way to oorganize the files in folders too, with this one command:

exiftool '-Directory<CreateDate' -d /media/ingest/newfolder/%y/%y%m -r /media/ingest/oldfolder

Thank you very much, now I'm done with all the images I have around :)